# N people drop their own key into a basket, after shuffling, every one randomly pick one, X is number of people get their own key. what is E(X),Var(X)?

Tags: probability

$N$ people drop their own key into a basket, after shuffling, every one randomly pick one, $X$ is number of people get their own key. what is $E(X)$,$\mathrm{Var}(X)$?

Comment: Where is your attempt? What is the probability that all persons get their own keys?

Comment: You should find $E[X]$ easy to answer.  What is the probability a particular individual gets their own key?

Answer (score 3):

Use linearity of expectation, indicator random variables, and remember that $Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$

Let $X = X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n$ where $X_i = \begin{cases} 1&\text{if person}~i~\text{gets their key}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

You correctly found that $Pr(X_i=1)=\frac{1}{n}$ and as such $E[X] = n\cdot \frac{1}{n}=1$

Now, consider $X^2 = (X_1+X_2+\dots+X_n)^2 = X_1^2+X_2^2+\dots+X_n^2 + X_1X_2 + X_1X_3+\dots+X_nX_{n-1}$

$X_i^2 = X_i$ so those terms are easy to deal with.  $X_iX_j$ with $i\neq j$ on the other hand will equal $1$ if and only if both persons $i$ and $j$ receive their keys.

We have for $i\neq j$ that $Pr(X_iX_j=1) = Pr(X_i=1)Pr(X_j=1\mid X_i=1) = \frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{n-1}$

Now, taking note of the number of occurrences of each and letting $i\neq j$ we have:

$E[X^2] = n\cdot E[X_i] + n(n-1)\cdot E[X_iX_j] = n\cdot \frac{1}{n} + n(n-1)\cdot \frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n-1} = 1 + 1=2$

So, $Var(X) = E[X^2]-E[X]^2 = 2 - 1^2 = 1$

Answer (score 1):

Expected value is easy to calculate; every person has an equal chance of pulling his own key.

The first is uniformly distributed. The second can only pull his key if the first guy did not pull it, and so on.

$E(X) = $
$$\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n-1}*\frac{n-1}{n}+ \frac{1}{n-2}*\frac{n-2}{n-1}*\frac{n-1}{n} +...$$

$$=1$$

$VAR(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2 $

let  $Y_i$  denote whether or not person $i$ managed to find his own key.

then $E(X^2) = E(Y_iY_j) $     for all $i,j$

note that distinct $i, j$ result in $E(Y_iY_j)=$ $$\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$$
The number of distinct pairs is $n(n-1)/2$

By linearity of expectation you get that $E(X^2) = 2$ 
hence:

$VAR(X) = 2 - 1 = 1$